# How to add a domain name in local with Apache?

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost, domain-name

I have a website which I used to deploy in localhost running the command: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start` and then typing the URL: `http://XXX/myfirstphpsite/src` where XXX is my IP address and myfirstphpsite/src the repertory containing my website.

However, now I want to type the following URL:
`http://pharaohohparis.tld` instead of the last URL to deploy in local my website.

For that, I did the following:

1. I went to the repertory: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and created a new file named: `pharaohofparis.tld.conf` in which I inserted:

   > ```
   > <VirtualHost *:80>
   >     ServerName pharaohofparis.tld
   >     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myfirstphpsite/src
   >
   >     <Directory /var/www/html/myfirstphpsite/src>
   >         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
   >         AllowOverride All
   >         Order allow,deny
   >         Allow from all
   >     </Directory>
   > </VirtualHost>
   > ```
2. I actived the virtual host by typing:

> sudo a2ensite pharaohofparis.tld.conf
> sudo service apache2 reload

3. I edited the file `/etc/hosts` by adding the line:

> ```
> 127.0.0.1       pharaohofparis.tld
> ```

However, when I type the URL: `http://pharaohofparis.tld`, I got the DNS error "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN". How can I fix this ?

**EDIT: THE PROBLEM WAS LINUX SUBSYSTEM. THERE WAS NO PROBLEM IS A REAL UBUNTU.**

Comment: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/dns_probe_finished_nxdomain/, looks like a DNS client cache issue.  Other thing to check in /etc/nsswitch.conf, does it mention `files` on the `hosts` line?  You need this so it will check the local hosts file for DNS resolution.

Comment: I cleaned the cash and I still got this issue. Besides, indeed it mentions  `files dns ` in the  `hosts ` line.

Comment: In a terminal, type `nslookup http:///pharaohofparis.tld`, it should return your localhost IP.  If not, fix that first.  If it does not help, put `LogLevel debug` in your httpd.conf.  In your VirtualHost *:80, add a new error_log and new CustomLog.  This way you will split the logs between your general configuration and that specific VirtualHost.  And try again. Hopefully these logs will help.  Et psst, répertoire c'est "directory" en anglais :)

Comment: The `nslookup` command returns me my current IP address and not `127.0.0.1`. I think the problem may be in the fact that I am using WSL (Linux Subsystem) and thus my Windows OS is using another configuration to deploy websites. Anyway, I plan on installing a dualboot and try this again. I will let you know if it worked. Besides, sorry for the delay of my response. Et merci pour l'info. :)

Comment: ah, could it be that the Windows firewall is blocking it?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem of firewall. However, every time I started my pc, the /etc/hosts file was reset (the line I added in step 3 was missing), but even when adding it again and try immediately after, it doesn't work. Anyway, I installed a dual boot Ubuntu recently, and after doing the steps I mentioned in my post, there was no errors; all worked fine. So it was indeed a problem of Linux Sub System. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my Edit above: the problem was apparently Linux Subsystem. There was no problem is a real Ubuntu.